# "granted" is to "granted to" as "deprived of" is to what?

Tags: verbs

I'm trying to edit a manuscript and I can't find the correct words.

If "people were granted power," then "power was granted to people."

If "people were deprived of power," then what words would complete the sentence "power was [?] people"?

Comment: It's a somewhat "literary, formal" construction, but *Power was **denied** people* requires no preposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Deprived" doesn't work two-ways as 'granted' does.

You could say:

> Power was *withheld* from people.

Comment: Thank you very much.  This answers my question.  I'm sorry I can't upvote it yet; I will when I get the needed reputation.

Comment: Would "power was denied to people" also be acceptable?

Comment: Denied was what I was about to say, yeah. It's about as close in meaning as anything is.

Comment: @the-baby-is-you, thanks.

Comment: @user338955 I'd have no problem with "denied", but the reason I went with "withheld" is that I felt it was closest to 'deprived'. When you're deprived of something, it means you are being prevented from something you should have access to. "Withheld" means that the thing you want is there, but being held back. "Denied" can be used to mean you have been refused something you are entitled to, but it can also mean something you are **not** by rights entitled to. For example, if an application for citizenship was denied, it could be on legal grounds - it was never yours to have.

Comment: @Astralbee That's a good point, I was having trouble putting my finger on the difference but I think you're right.